# Validate dynamic input form elements using Validator Plugin Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, jquery-validate

I am using this  http://jqueryvalidation.org/ jquery validation plugin.

HTML dynamic form will be like this

```
<form name="baby_book" id="baby_book">
<input name="form_elements[16]" id="form_elements[16]">
<input name="form_elements[17]" id="form_elements[17]">
<input name="form_elements[18]" id="form_elements[18]">

<a class="myfont baby_book_save" href="javascript:void(0)"  onclick="validatefilesizeform('save')" >Save</a> 
</form>
```

My JS Code will be like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var validator="";

$(document).ready(function(){

var max_length_rules= <?php echo json_encode($valid_rules); ?>;

validator=$("#baby_book").validate();

     $.each(max_length_rules,function(k,v){

             $.each(v, function(key, value){

                   $('input[id="'+key+'"]').rules('add',"required"); 
                });
        });

});

function validatefilesizeform(type)
{
    if(type == 'save')
     {
         document.baby_book.sec_submit.value="save";

         if(validator.form())
         {
            document.baby_book.submit();
         }
    }

</script>
```

While applying dynamic rules like that it doesn't validate the form.

In console it displays this error

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'form' of undefined**

Can anyone help me how to add dyanmic rules . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's because when the browser finds the `validatefilesizeform('save')` in the `onclick` attribute, it evaluates that expression, i.e runs the function. With this syntax you're asigning the result of that evaluation to the `onclick` event, which is not what you want.

The `Cannot read property 'form' of undefined` error happens because in that moment the `$(document).ready()` callback has not yet been executed, and, when the function tries to execute `validator.form()`, that variable is already undefined. It will be initialized later, inside the `$(document).ready()`.

To get the expected behavior, and avoid the error, you must change the `onclick` handler to this one:

```
`onclick="function() { validatefilesizeform('save') }"`
```

In this case you're registering a function as the value for the `onclick` attribute. And this function will be evaluated when the control is clicked.

To make it even more clear:

```
// This is the value returned by the function evaluation:
validatefilesizeform('save')

// This is a function
function() { validatefilesizeform('save'); }
```

So the second is a function that can be evaluated. The first one evaluates the function. Handlers should always be functions, and not values.